# How do I keep the result of an operation from a conditional?

Tags: c++

Ok that title is bad, please feel free to suggest something better, I just don't know what to call it.

Suppose I have an object `a`, and I want to assign some value to it, check that this value meets some condition, then do something *if* the condition is met. Here is one way of doing this:

```
int a = 1234;
if (a > 1)
{
  someFunction(a);
}
```

But what if I don't need `a` outside of this test? If I try to do `if(int a = 1234 > 1)` then I get `a = 1` because it solves the right hand side first, and if I put the definition in a bracket I get this:

```
if ((int a = 1234) > 1) // about 3 different errors
{
  someFunction(a);
}
```

Obviously this isn't a deal-breaker, but since you can declare objects inside `for` loops I thought it might be possible to achieve something similar with `if` conditions?

Comment: You can't do this. You can declare one variable, initialize it and have its value checked. For anything else, it needs to go before the `if` statement.

Comment: and thats why you might get left hand side must be var or expression error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this previously using a custom type that contains a value and the result of a comparison:

```
struct int_comparison {
    int value;
    bool comparison;
    int_comparison(int value): value(value), comparison() {}
    int_comparison &operator>(int rhs) {
        comparison = value > rhs;
        return *this;
    }
    explicit operator bool() const { return comparison; }
};

if (auto i = int_comparison(1234) > 1) {
    std::cout << i.value << '\n';
}
```

This is in general fairly hard to follow; better usually to use a nested scope:

```
{
    int i = 1234;
    if (i > 1) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully, a TS after C++14 will allow a further pattern using [`optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) and a lambda:

```
if (auto i = ([](int i) { return i > 1 ? std::optional<int>{i} : std::nullopt; })(1234)) {
    std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

This uses the `operator bool` on `optional` that returns whether it is in the engaged state.

Comment: seems like a prime candidate for a template

Comment: btw. you can do it without the lambda. `if (auto b = i > 5 ? std::make_optional<int>(5) : std::nullopt)` works perfectly fine

Comment: @PeterT the lambda is so that you don't have to repeat the value `1234` (it could be expensive to calculate).

Answer (score 1):

```
(int a = 1234)
```

This is a **statement** and has no return value, so you cannot compare it against anything.

This is the reason you are getting errors when trying to compare it to 1 on this line:

```
if ((int a = 1234) > 1)
```